# Image not rendering in UIImageView

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview

This image, generated by the function below refuses to show up in a UIImageView

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f65yxsqxzqqies/soundwave.png?dl=0

Is this an iOS issue or an error while generating the image?

Thank you

```
private func plotLogGraph(_ samples: [CGFloat], maximumValue max: CGFloat, zeroValue min: CGFloat, imageHeight: CGFloat,color:UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(samples.count), height: imageHeight)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }

    context.setAlpha(1.0)
    context.setLineWidth(1.0)
    context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)

    let sampleDrawingScale: CGFloat
    if max == min {
        sampleDrawingScale = 0
    } else {
        sampleDrawingScale = imageHeight / 2 / (max - min)
    }
    let verticalMiddle = imageHeight / 2
    for (x, sample) in samples.enumerated() {
        let height = (sample - min) * sampleDrawingScale
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: verticalMiddle - height))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: verticalMiddle + height))
        context.strokePath();
    }
    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        return nil;
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image;
}
```

Example for rendering is just a fullscreen ImageView displaying the image, see
https://github.com/jonathanort/ImageTest

Comment: What do you mean it refuses to show up in an imageview? the image from the dropbox works fine in an imageview

Comment: Show your code.  Show how you're assigning the image to the imageView, etc.

Comment: Example for rendering is just a fullscreen ImageView displaying the image, see https://github.com/jonathanort/ImageTest